# Is this sentence grammatically correct? Didn't in interrogative sentence

Tags: grammaticality

> Did he did not see her?

The context was the man ignore a girl when they passed each other, and her friend commented on him.

The double "did" seems funny to me.

Comment: Maybe the sentence is "Did he _or_ did he not see her?". That must have been misprint.

Comment: In addition to @HimabinduBoddupalli's comment, if the friend was commenting *to the girl*, it would be 'did he not see you?' or 'did he or did he not see you?'. You're right that the two 'did's are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

> Did he not see her?

When you put the auxiliary verb at the front of the clause to form a question, you need to get rid the original. You're **moving** it not **adding** it.